# How to set auto_sampling on in dashdb

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashdb

I setup a dashdb trial. I want to turn on AUTO_SAMPLING but the default userid does not have the admin authority to do this. So how do I get this done?

Answer (score 1):

That is not exposed right now.  Dashdb right now has some of these admin settings hidden for now.  The reason behind this is because the DashDB service is a shared service and some default settings have been set.

There is plans to expose some of this eventually though...

Comment: @data_guy could you please accept an answer so this can be closed out?